# GoogleWebMasterTools: duplicated description meta tag

Tags: google-search-console

I have noticed that in the Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools) two of my URLs show up with duplicated description meta tag. The URLs are :

1. `www.example.com/blog/`
2. `www.example.com/blog/page/2/`

Obviously they correspond to the pagination of my blog home page. Is there a way to fix this?

[EDIT]
I forgot to mention I use Wordpress.

Comment: Have you considered changing the descriptions?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how since it is only one blog page but with paginated content. So I can only change the description at one place

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick and dirty fix for it if you install all in one SEO plugin
and then you go to "Remove Descriptions For Paginated Pages" so that meta descriptions will not show on page 2 / page 3 / page 4 and so on...

After 1 week, the error in google webmaster tools will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

[Pagination with rel=“next” and rel=“prev”](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html)

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/blog/page/2/" />
<link rel="prev" href="/blog/" />
<link rel="next" href="/blog/page/3" />
```

The prev/next say to bots "You're on a section of the site which has pages. The canonical is where you are now, treat the `prev` url as the previous page and the `next` as next page, all with the same sort of content, so the duplicate is because of the pages".

Comment: yes, that's what I said in my post :) But I'm using Wordpress (that, I forgot to mention) and I don't know how to set a different description to each page. In fact, I don't think I should. I think I should somehow indicate to google that these URLs are for pagination.

Comment: This isn't about description, this is about telling bots that you get the same result, just page X of it. This doesn't require you to set description per page (yes, would be a bit better, but not needed).

Answer (score 0):

Its tricky but I believe best way to handle this issue is that don't use the Meta description tag on both pages. If your page have content, Google will automatically crawl the content from pages.